# how to be attached to a another user Byobu session

Tags: byobu

I love byobu, and I want to be attached from my user in a remote server to an another user byobu session, already existing.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and this is my byobu version:

```
$ byobu -v
byobu version 5.74
tmux 1.8
```

I tried to list byobu sessions, but it did not work:

```
$ byobu ls
failed to connect to server
```

or:

```
$ byobu-select-session 
failed to connect to server
ambiguous command: , could be: attach-session, bind-key, break-pane, capture-pane, choose-buffer, choose-client, choose-list, choose-session, choose-tree, choose-window, clear-history, clock-mode, command-prompt, confirm-before, copy-mode, delete-buffer, detach-client, display-message, display-panes, find-window, has-session, if-shell, join-pane, kill-pane, kill-server, kill-session, kill-window, last-pane, last-window, link-window, list-buffers, list-clients, list-commands, list-keys, list-panes, list-sessions, list-windows, load-buffer, lock-client, lock-server, lock-session, move-pane, move-window, new-session, new-window, next-layout, next-window, paste-buffer, pipe-pane, previous-layout, previous-window, refresh-client, rename-session, rename-window, resize-pane, respawn-pane, respawn-window, rotate-window, run-shell, save-buffer, select-layout, select-pane, select-window, send-keys, send-prefix, server-info, set-buffer, set-environment, set-option, set-window-option, show-buffer, show-environment, show-messages, show-options, show-window-options, source-file, split-window, start-server, suspend-client, swap-pane, swap-window, switch-client, unbind-key, unlink-window, wait-for
```

**Why are these commands failing?**

**How can I attach to another user bybou session?**

Answer (score 0):

I usually achieve this by first becoming the target user via `sudo`, and launching byobu as that user:

```
sudo -i -u targetuser
byobu
```